# _imex_ error in sas

Tags: sas

When I use PROC IMPORT for importing data from an excel file I get an error something like "*IMEX*". My excel is an older version.

If I change it to a newer version and run the same code I'm able to import the data.

Is there any way to import data from an older version of an excel?

Comment: Please update your question with an example of the PROC IMPORT statement and the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: Please also provide the versions of Excel, SAS, and the OS you are running.